# Why would cvs check in a diff instead of a file?

Tags: cvs

I did a checkout recently, and one of the files was not the file that I checked in, but rather it was a `diff` of that file and the previous version.

Is `cvs` known for this kind of error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure it was a 'diff' of that file and the previous file?

I aske because if two developers work on the same line(s) of the same file, the second `cvs commit` can cause cvs to leave two versions of the same line(s) in place, with extra lines that have '>>>>>' or '<<<<<' in them.

Do `cvs log thefileinquestion` and see what the commit history looks like.  You may see the problem there.

Comment: In other words, this is an unresolved merge conflict. Some human being has to decide how to resolve the conflict.

Answer (score 1):

It seem that someone forced a commit, but there were conflicts.
You should check who committed this version, because it is a signal of uneducated use of CVS.

If the `cvs status` or a failing `cvs commit` indicates unresolved conflicts you have to search through the conflicting file for `>>>>>>` lines and decide on which of the two conflicting parts (on until `++++` the other from that to `<<<<`) is the valid one, edit and merge the 'unconflicted' version.

You can also use [xxdiff](http://furius.ca/xxdiff/) to unmerge these conflicts. That program is also availble with many distros